# Writing text on 16-bit grayscale images in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to draw text onto a 16 bit grayscale image in Python. I am using Numpy to create my 16 bit Ndimage.

I have tried PIL using mode `mode='L'`

```
a = np.zeros([rows,columns],dtype=np.uint16)
img = Image.fromarray(a,mode='L')

....

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
for i in range(1,32):
    draw.text((0,i*height), text + ' ' + str(i), font=font, fill=32*i)
```

It works up until I go over 255 (or 8 bits). Above fill values of 255 all values appear as 255 in the image.

Is there a way to get PIL to work with 16 bit grayscale or are there any other libraries in python that will allow me to write text on 16 bit images.

Comment: Are you sure your .fromarray() call really gives you the bitmap you expect? I tried filling the 'a' array with a gradient from 0 to 65535, but what I got was not what I expected. It seems every array element (of type uint16) results in two pixels in the image!

Comment: PIL should be able to work with 16-bit images. Try using mode "L;16". By default, the "L" mode is 8-bit.

Comment: @gavinb with mode='L;16' I get unrecognised mode

Comment: @MichielOvertoom Yes. I hadn't tested that but I also get unexpected results

Comment: Which version are you using? AFAICT the supported modes are: http://svn.effbot.org/public/pil/libImaging/Unpack.c

Comment: @gavinb I am using version 1.1.7. I see your point. My code is `img = Image.fromarray(a,mode='L;16')` but throws unrecognised mode